# Involve Model's from two different .js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Having -

**default.html**

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
        <script src="Model1.js"></script>
        <script src="Model2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Model1.js**

```
...
Model1 = Backbone.View.extend();
```

**Model2.js**

```
...
Model2 = Backbone.View.extend(
    initialize: function(){
    this.model1 = new Model1();
    },
);
```

it gives an error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: Model1 is not defined`.

However , all entire in single `.html` it workout fine -

**default.html**

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <script>
    ...
    Model1 = Backbone.View.extend();
     ...
    Model2 = Backbone.View.extend(
        initialize: function(){
        this.model1 = new Model1();
        },
      };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How could I make it work keeping the 1st page's partition ?

Comment: Are you calling them after document ready?

Comment: `script` tag could be in the `head` no?

Comment: for some reasons the `script` tag is in the `body` in my case ,it doesn't matter...

Comment: Where is Backbone loaded?

Comment: I get a syntax error in your code and you get a runtime error.  I think you are posting different code than what is failing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test page just like this and added underscore.js and backbone.js (I assume your page has it).

I get the following error in Chrome developer tools:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : Model2.js:2
```

This is because your object literal in Model2 is not in curly braces.

Change that code block to this and it works:

```
Model2 = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
    this.model1 = new Model1();
    },
});
```

Note that the indentation is a little off.  You should indent the contents of the initialize function.

Comment: I edited the question , it just was my spelling . Still I have the same error .